# Clipping Mask Issue: "Cannot make Mask"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I'm SO frustrated! I mocked up this design the other day with no issues and today none of the functions are working. I dragged my image in, placed it behind the letter I want to use as a mask, selected both, then got this message???
[image: CLipping Mask issue]

Answer (score 1):

Being able to see your layers panel would clarify, but the message is pretty self-explanitory:

> The selection **cannot contain objects within different groups** unless the entire group is selected.

You have objects from different groups selected. I assume that the entire word is a group but you only have one letter selected. Either select the goup, or ungroup and select the letter.

Comment: wont that mask the whole word?

Comment: Oh, wait-- you mean to ungroup first? (I'm a newbie- forgive me!)

Comment: If you only want to use the path of the one letter then yes, ungroup until you have the path on its own and not in any groups

Comment: I've tried grouped and un-groups and I've now re-made this 5 times with no luck.

Comment: The only reason that message would show is because you're selecting grouped objects. Could you update your question with a screenshot of your layers panel?

Answer (score 0):

duplicate the same word & ungroup until you have the needed path. Make it colorless and clip mask separately with the image and place your mask back where you want it on the word & group the whole thing. Make sure to delete the existing path on the word.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

That's not self-explanatory at all. That message comes up when inside the group there are hidden layers. Simply delete or unhide those layers and it will work